# Add subview outside viewDidLoad Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a UILabel from a method.

```
- (void)setDesc:(NSString *)desc
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake(200,200,100,100)];
    label.text = desc;
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

This method is in Class2, and it's called from Class1 like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    desc = @"Sometext";
    [class2obj setDesc:desc]; // class2obj is an object of class2 declared earlier
}
```

The label isn't updated, only if I change it in the ViewDidLoad in class2. Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post your viewDidLoad code that isn't working?

Comment: In reality calling `self.view` triggers `viewDidLoad` if the view isn't previously loaded. I would check your frame to ensure its on screen. And I would suggest setting the `AutoResizingMask` or using autoLayout. There is nothing that would prevent you from adding a view at anytime.

Comment: No matter how If you add the code in viewDidLoad or call the methods. If you call the method in the same place than you put the code in viewDidLoad the behavior will be the same. If you call the methods several lines before in the next line you put some line of method what add another view you might not see the label.

Comment: Actually I'm calling a setter method (for a property) from another class and trying to change the label from there. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call it before [super viewDidLoad]?

Use [label setBackGroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]] to be sure the label isn't added.

Try [label sizeToFit] because maybe there is a problem with numberOfLines = 4;

Comment: Actually I'm calling a setter method (for a property) from another class and trying to change the label from there. Does this change anything?

Comment: Huh? Give us more details please 'cause it's not very clear ^^'

Comment: In your viewDidLoad method, add this please
NSLog("ViewDidLoad %p", self);

And when you call [class2obj setDesc:desc] add
NSLog("Add desc %p", class2obj);

Are they the same pointers?

Comment: Aaahh no they are different... then there must be something wrong with the object right?

Comment: Exactly, you don't send the setDesc message to the good instance ;) Do you need help for that? :)

Comment: I allocate and initialize the object in viewDidLoad in Class1 (where setDesc is called), is this wrong. (I guess I need help for that) thanks for your patient

Comment: You really should show us more code, but it looks complicated. You're not supposed to allocate and init a viewController. It's done when you display it.

Comment: Ok so there is no easy way to access that object then?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `UILabel` object with an `NSString` object. `UILabel *label = desc;`

That's just bad. If you want to create a new label programatically you do:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[label setText:@"text"];
[label setFont:myFont];
[label setTextColor:myTextColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Oh sorry it's the text property that's supposed to be `desc`, the label is allocated and initialized with a frame as it should be done